# Opening files from Filezilla to console Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, filezilla

Sometimes I have the need to modify files that are in a FTP server, currently I have Filezilla  opening them in sublime. But I'm moving to VIM and I haven't found a way to make the file open in VIM console. Probably works flawless for gVim but anyone have this working on the console?

Answer (score 7):

I managed to have a console pop up with `vim` by invoking a custom shell script wrapper instead of vim itself.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e "vim $1"
```

One of the drawbacks is that everytime a new window will pop up. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This topic is quite old but Vim stays the best ! So, I'd like to share my experience.

I'm using **Guake Terminal** and **Vim v8** on a **Debian 9.2** environment. The solution posted by @soulseekah is great but does not allow multiple files open in this configuration.

As the accepted solution, we will need a bash script. The difference will be that we check if vim is running. If no, run it. If yes, open the file in a new tab.

Here we go :

```
#!/bin/bash

if pgrep -x "vim" > /dev/null ; then
    guake -e ":tabedit $1";
else
    guake -e "vim $1" 
fi
```

**Downsides :**

- Need to be in normal mode to open new files.
- Not working with gnome-terminal.

Enjoy guys !

Answer (score 0):

I use [Midnight Commander](http://www.gnu.org/software/mc/) to do the same thing & it works with console Vim as well as a lot of very useful other commands.